# Having trouble extracting the string value from a tensor with datatype tf.string

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm writing an NN which requires text (as a string) to be fed in as a placeholder in Tensorflow. I'm having trouble figuring out how to extract the string from the placeholder, which must hold a tensor object. I tried initializing and interactive session and then calling placeholder.eval(), but I got an error because in the initial run, before the text is fed into the placeholder, I got an error because the placeholder was empty. Can anyone give me any pointers on how to do this?

Here's my code for reference.

```
def train_1(self):

    real_image_size = 256
    text_input = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string)
    real_image = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = (real_image_size, real_image_size, 3))

    text_input = text_input[0][0]

    all_captions = self.caption_arr
    rand_idx = np.random.random()*11788
    fake_caption = all_captions[int(rand_idx)]
    while text_input == fake_caption:
        rand_idx = np.random.random()*len(captions)
        fake_caption = all_captions[rand_idx]

    fake_image_size = 64
    fake_image = self.generator_1(text_input)
    real_result_real_caption = discriminator_1(real_image, text_input)
    real_result_fake_caption = discriminator_1(real_image, fake_caption)
    fake_result = discriminator_1(fake_image, text_input)

    dis_loss = tf.reduce_mean(real_result_fake_caption) + tf.reduce_mean(fake_result) - tf.reduce_mean(real_result_real_caption)
    gen_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(fake_result)

    t_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
    d_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'dis' in var.name]
    g_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'gen' in var.name]

    trainer_dis = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 1e-4).minimize(d_loss, var_list = d_vars)
    trainer_gen = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 1e-4).minimize(g_loss, var_list = g_vars)
    # sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    # sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    # sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # text_input = text_input.eval({text_input : [[""]]})
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        batch_size = 1
        num_of_imgs = 11788
        num_epochs = 1000 #adjust if necessary
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

        print('Start Training::: ')
        for i in range(num_epochs):
            print(str(i) + 'th epoch: ')
            feeder = pr.FeedExamples()
            num_of_batches = int(num_of_imgs/batch_size)
            for j in range(num_of_batches):
                #Training the Discriminator.
                for k in range(5):
                    train_data = feeder.next_example()
                    train_image = train_data[0]
                    txt = train_data[1]
                    feed_txt = tf.constant([[txt]])
                    _, dLoss = sess.run([dis_loss, trainer_dis],
                                        feed_dict = {text_input : feed_txt, real_image : train_image})
                        #Training the Generator.
                for k in range(1):
                    train_data = feeder.curr_example()
                    train_image = train_data[0]
                    txt = train_data[1]
                    _, gLoss = sess.run([gen_loss, trainer_gen],
                                        feed_dict = {text_input : tf.constant([[txt]]), real_image : train_image})


                print('Discriminator Loss: ' + str(dLoss))
                print('Generator Loss: ' + str(gLoss))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder

> Inserts a placeholder for a tensor that will be always fed.
>
> **Important**: This tensor will produce an error if evaluated. Its value
>   must be fed using the feed_dict optional argument to `Session.run()`,
>   `Tensor.eval()`, or `Operation.run()`.

A [placeholder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) does not have a value other than the value you feed in. That is the difference to a [variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables).

Although a *variable* wouldn't make much sense in your case since you are talking about the input. Therefore it is not clear what you are actually trying to achieve.

I would suggest to reduce the example to a minimal example (e.g. single *placeholder*, *variable* or *operation*). It will also help you to understand TensorFlow better.